# Single Div refresh with jquery Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay So I have a div on my page that has some code for display option groups in a select input. And then on the other side displaying the options in that group after the selection is made. My html/php code for this is below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label class="control-label" for="productOptions">Select your
        product options</label> <select class="form-control" id=
        "productOptions">
            <option>
                Select an Option Group
            </option><?php foreach($DefaultOptions as $option): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $option['GroupID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $option['GroupName']; ?>
            </option><?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6" id="groupOptions">
        <label class="control-label">Group Options</label>
        <?php if($GroupOptions): ?>
        <?php foreach ($GroupOptions as $optionValue): ?>
        <?php echo $optionValue['optionName']; ?> <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default on the original page load, `$GroupOptions` does not exist in the form, because it is set after the user selects the Group they wish to choose from. I call the php script by using ajax to `avoid page reload`

```
$("#productOptions").change(function(){

    var GroupID = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'GroupID=' + GroupID;
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "#",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $("#groupOptions").html(dataString);
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then the ajax goes to a php call that gets the options that match the groups id in the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['GroupID']))
{
    $GroupID = $_POST['GroupID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from `KC_Options` WHERE GroupID=$GroupID";

    $GroupOptions = $db->query($sql);
}
```

Now I want to `refresh` the div `#GroupOptions` to display the results from the query above, and make `<?php if($GroupOptions): ?>` set to true.

I managed to refresh the div with `$("#groupOptions").html(dataString);` in the success function of the ajax call. But that only returns well the dataString. (obviously). Is there a way to truly refresh just the div. Or a way to pass the info from the php call into the success function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You have 4 problems in your current code:

Problem #1 and Problem #2 -  In your separate PHP script you are not echoing anything back to the Ajax. Anything you echo will go back as a variable to the `success` function. Simply the add echo statement(s) according to the format you want. Your 2nd problem is that you are trying to echo it in the HTML part, where `$GroupOptions` does not even exist (the Ajax simply returns an output from the PHP script, it's not an `include` statement so your variables are not in the same scope).

```
if(isset($_POST['GroupID']))
{
    $GroupID = $_POST['GroupID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from `KC_Options` WHERE GroupID=$GroupID";

    $GroupOptions = $db->query($sql);

    //this is where you want to iterate through the result and echo it (will be sent as it to the success function as a variable)
    if($GroupOptions): 
      foreach ($GroupOptions as $optionValue): 
        echo $optionValue['optionName'];
      endforeach; 
    endif; 
}
```

In your Ajax, add a variable named `data` to the success function, which will receive the output from the PHP script. Also notice that your url is incorrect, you need to post to an actual external file such as `my_custom_script.php`.:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_external_script.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
       if (data && data !== '') {
         //data will equal anything that you echo in the PHP script
         //we're adding the label to the html so you don't override it with the new output
         var output = '<label class="control-label">Group Options</label>';
         output += data;
         $("#groupOptions").html(output);
       } else {//nothing came back from the PHP script
         alert('no data received!');
       }
      }
    });
```

Problem #4 - And on your HTML, no need to run any PHP. Simply change:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" id="groupOptions">
        <label class="control-label">Group Options</label>
        <?php if($GroupOptions): ?>
        <?php foreach ($GroupOptions as $optionValue): ?>
        <?php echo $optionValue['optionName']; ?> <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-lg-6" id="groupOptions">

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is echoing out `hello world` like it should, but then it's reloading the whole page inside that one div. See: http://i1309.photobucket.com/albums/s627/mievan123/Capture_zps6ee0ffb1.png

Comment: @user3271851 I've updated my answer. Should be working!

Comment: You need to debug the output. Put `console.log(data);` in your success function and we'll be able to see what's happening.

Comment: It outputs: `<p>Runts</p><!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>...` As the whole page continues.

Comment: OK, that's because your POST url is `#`. change it to your actual external PHP script. You are posting to the same page(~). That's never a good idea :) I've updated my answer.

Comment: I fixed it by placing `return false;` after the php code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the response in yout success callback function and actually give a response in your oho function

$("#productOptions").change(function(){

```
    var GroupID = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'GroupID=' + GroupID;
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "#",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(dataString) {        //take the response here
        // convert dataString to html...
        $("#groupOptions").html(newHtml);
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['GroupID']))
{
    $GroupID = $_POST['GroupID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from `KC_Options` WHERE GroupID=$GroupID";

    $GroupOptions = $db->query($sql);
    echo json_encode($GroupOptions );         //give a response here using json
}
```