# php update main page when div content is updated

Tags: php

I have a "home" page: `home.php`, that contains a "banner" for my website.  On this banner is a box that shows the user a number, (think Facebook notifications..)

[image]

The actual page that loads, `home.php`, is only a placeholder, as most of what happens on the "page" happens in `<div>` elements that exist inside `home.php`.  When the user takes an action on a page inside a `<div>` element on `home.php`, I'd like the "notification" to refresh, but I'm not sure how to do that since `home.php` is not ever refreshing itself - only the div content is refreshing, (ajax, etc.)

In my `home.php`, the code to display this is:

```
<div class="navbar-userData">
<?php
    $count = count($_SESSION['cost']);
    echo "<img class=\"hoverButton\" id=\"hoverButton\" src=\"../../img/button.png\">";
    echo $count;

?>
</div>
```

The user will take actions that will push an additional item onto the end of `$_SESSION['cost']`, and when they do that, the the count of `$_SESSION['cost']` will increase, but it will not refresh to the user until they refresh the page, (which I don't want.)

Is there a way for me to trigger this bit of code to auto-refresh, or use jquery in my ajax success call to reload `<div class="navbar-userData">`?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681278/single-div-refresh-with-jquery-ajax-and-php

Comment: sweet, I'll have a look.  Thank you!

Comment: Create a file to read notification count. Create a function to read that file and change the notification number. On each call success, call the function to refresh notification count. That's how I'd do it if it was upon user interaction

Comment: That's a really good idea........ I like it and it's simple to do :)  Thank you!